# Correct usage of process.exit in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, process

I'd like to start off by saying that I'm a complete NodeJS noobie.

So, that being said, I'm trying to get a better understanding of the behavior of parent and child processes when using the Cluster API of NodeJS along with `process.exit`. I also realize that all of these doubts relate to the behavior of Unix itself.

I know that `process.exit()` causes the current process to exit with the "success" code, `0`.

For my test, I have 2 files: `index.js` and `indexWorker.js`.

Here's what `index.js` looks like:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    // Setup the required fork behavior.
    cluster.setupMaster({
            exec: 'indexWorker.js'
    });

    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each logical core.
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i) {
        cluster.fork({'NODE_ENV': 'development'});
    }

    console.log('Calling process.exit on parent.');
    process.exit();

}
```

And here's what `indexWorker.js` looks like:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

console.log("Started worker having ID: " + cluster.worker.id);
```

**Here are my questions/doubts:**

**Doubt 1**

Now, since I'm using `process.exit` on the parent, my understanding is that all the worker process ought to become orphan process. However, firstly, the control doesn't return to my terminal window until I do a `^C`, despite the fact that the parent (`index.js`) is exiting right away. Also, `ps`, `ps -ax`, `ps -elf | grep <pattern>` don't seem to think that there are any node programs running.
So my doubt is: why isn't the control returning to the terminal and why isn't `ps` showing me anything?

**Doubt 2**

If I remove `process.exit` from `index.js`, my understanding is that the control doesn't return to my terminal because despite the parent having finished it's task, the child processes are running and thus the parent hasn't exited. Is that a correct understanding or am I missing something?

**Doubt 3**

If I remove the `cluster.fork` call and `process.exit()` call  from `index.js`, the script completes and returns control to my terminal window immediately, as `index.js` isn't doing much in that case.

However, as you can see, `indexWorker.js` isn't doing any long operations either. It's simply printing a console message. Why, in that case, are the processes still running? Shouldn't the behavior be the same as the parent's, i.e. exit on script completion and thereby eventually return control to the terminal window?

I've simply been running `node index.js` for all these tests; never putting any processes in the background. My tests are being run on a Mac.

That's all the doubts I have, for now. :)

I've basically been experimenting by putting `process.exit` in different places and running `ps`, hence my doubts around these points. If there are any more things that you'd like to point out regarding the parent/child process behavior that aren't covered in my doubts, I'd greatly appreciate it! It'll definitely help me and the community in some way.

So, thanks in advance to the SO community!

Cheers!

Comment: most of your doubts are related to unix based system, using node.js javascript into your research doesn't make a difference you will get the same behavior with process as you would with any scripting or system language.

Comment: I thought as much. So thanks for corroborating. :) It's good that I'll have the same behavior, should I be using a different technology for development. However, I'm currently using Node, so if there are any finer details that I ought to know about the cluster API, in addition to what it's doing on the Unix level, I'd be happy to get that info as well.